# Incrementing an NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math, increment, nsnumber

New to obj-C and Cocoa here

I'm trying to just increment a variable in a method and, being used to C++, I want to just use the terminology of variable++, but that doesn't work on an NSNumber, so I've come up with

> player1Points = [NSNumber numberWithInt: ([ player1Points intValue ] + 1) ];

I am tempted to just redeclare player1Points as an int in the header, but I want to keep @synthesize and @property so that I don't have to write get and set routines.

Is there an easier way to write this line of code?

Comment: You can use `@synthesize` and `@property` with an `int` property.

Comment: Take a look [NSNumber Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still declare it NSInteger, a property may be a primitive type as well:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger player1Points;
```

You can still synthesize it.

Alternatively, there is a new syntax which will make the use of NSNumber more comfortable:

```
player1Points = @(player1Points.integerValue+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use primitives as properties, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int player1Points;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all the answers, one other option (although perhaps over coding), is to create a category on `NSNumber` with an instance method called increase (or something else). So you can have something like `[player1Points increase];` anywhere in your app.